# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 not recognizing Local Server

Tags: ssms, ssms-2012

I'm a total newb to SSMS, but all of the tutorials I'm finding online gloss over the step where they start up the program and connect to their local server, their computer's name.  I'm on Windows 8, and ISS is installed and running correctly.  I'm not sure what else I could be missing.  Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot from sql server management studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localhost` as server name. Append `/instance_name` if you are using instances. For instance, if using SQL Express use `localhost/SQLExpress`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I got [this error](http://rodenbeek.com/images/screenshot-ssms-error.PNG)

Comment: Is this SQL Express? Try localhost\SQLExpress

Comment: Yeah.  I am embarrassed to say this is what my problem was.